# Make WinForms rich text box ignore the "CTRL + >" and "CTRL + <" hotkeys

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a rich text box which is enabled to `CTRL + >` (or `CTRL + <`) key shortcut which increases(or decreases) font size. I want to disable the key so that it will not change the font sizes. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try capturing `KeyDown` event like this:

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.KeyValue == 190 || e.KeyValue == 188) && e.Control && e.Shift)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```